# Explain work of lastIndexOf in this for loop

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain to me how exactly lastIndexOf works here?
To be specific: I do not understand how comparing str[i] !== i works here. How does it detect if the character is repeating?

This had to be a simple exercise to find if str has unique characters that are not going twice in the same str.

```
    isUnique('abcdef'),
    isUnique('89%df#$^a&'),
    isUnique('abcaef'));

function isUnique(str)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if(str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) !== i) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try logging `i`, `str[i]`, and `str.lastIndexOf(str[i])` to see what they are.

Comment: Because you don't want to count the letter your are searching for. So you search only *after* it. And since you are doing it from the start, you don't miss any letter.

Comment: `if(str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) !== str.indexOf(str[i])) return false;` for me this logic makes sense but I cannot figure out how could we compare let's say letter 'A' to the number i, like here `if(str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) !== i) return false;`

Comment: @ITgoldman — No, that would be `str.indexOf(str[i], i+1)`.

Comment: @MaxChergik Why would `str.lastIndexOf(str[i])` return a letter `A`...?

Comment: @MaxChergik — You aren't comparing a letter to a number. Log the values as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Ohhh, so in general saying I am counting i number from the left to right and at the same time I am checking on which position stays any symbol from light to left, which makes let's say str "ahswabn" where's the a position in i == 0 and where's a position from the lastIndexOf == 4, is that right?

Comment: @Quentin What is wrong with my analysis?

Answer (score 0):

assume you have a `string` like this: `'abcaef'`, let's start and check that if it is unique or not...

we start from first `char`: 0 and `str[0]` is `a` and if all chars in `str` are unique, we expect that `lastIndexOf("a")` return 0 but it return 3 and it means there is another `a` that it is not in position `0`

note that `lastIndexOf` return index from left, but it check from right and return index of first occurrence from right:

```
a b c a e f
0 1 2 3 4 5 <-
```